# Passing a parameter into a reducer function

Tags: javascript, reduce

I'm learning how to utilize reduce but still have a little bit of a mental block on the acc, val parameters.  My goal is to be able to pass additional parameters into a reducer function and feel pretty certain that I am just going about it the wrong way.

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5];

const multiply = (num, multiplier) => num * multiplier;

const multiplier = (acc, val) => acc += multiply(val, 4);

const result = array.reduce(multiplier);

console.log(result);
```

In this code block, I'm running the multiplier reducer against my array to multiple each value by 4.  This code works correctly and is all well and good, but I want to make it so that any value can be passed in instead of the hard coded 4.  I've tried things like

```
const multiplier = (acc, val, multiple) => acc += multiply(val, multiple);
const result = array.reduce(multiplier(4)
```

to be able to pass in a multiplier but the "acc, val" params are messing me up because I don't specifically "see" what the values are that are passed in.  I know that it passes in 1 then 2 then 3 etc. but how do you pass an additional parameter in such as a custom multiplier instead of needing a different multiplier function for every multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it as a currying function that will work as expected:

```
const multiplier = factor => (acc, val) => acc += multiply(val, factor);
const result = array.reduce(multiplier(4));
```

This way when you call `multiplier(4)` it will return a function tailored with the desired `factor` that you can use at your reducer like you intended to.

Comment: Hmm.  So that's still slightly perplexing to me and this probably because I am relatively new to using currying as well.  So we are passing 4 into multiplier.  Multiplier is passing that factor param into the reducer?  Is the reducer using it in the first function or just passing it along or do I just not understand this very well?

Comment: `multiplier(4)` returns another function that sets `factor` value. that returned function is used by the reducer. the returned function used by the reducer will be `(acc, val) => acc += multiply(val, 4)`, since you passed 4 as `factor` value

Comment: fwiw it's confusing at first for anyone though once you get it you will enjoy its flexibility. cheers!

Comment: That second explanation definitely adds some more clarity.  Thanks for the guidance!